# stop charging when battery full

Tags: c#, msdn

I want to stop charging laptop when it is full. I have tried using PowerManagement functions. Using them I can read the battery status but can't stop charging.

Is it possible?

How it can be achieved?

My code is :

```
Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus);
PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
PropertyInfo prop = null;
object propValue = null;
for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
{
    prop = pi[i];
    propValue = prop.GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null);
    int batteryLifePercent = (int)(SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
    if (batteryLifePercent == 100) 
    {
        // stop charging
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using reflection to look at the properties?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. The charging circuit in the laptop obviously will automatically stop charging the battery when it is full, otherwise it would blow it to hell...

Comment: @mason I think you mean reflection, but your question is valid.

Comment: @Rik Ha right you are. Silly R words.

Comment: @elgonzo In some cases the charge level may 100% but the charger always blinks (indicate charging).

Comment: Whatever that blinking LED means... It is very simple: If a Lithium ion/polymer battery is overcharged, it gets very hot, expands and delaminates, until either the battery itself or its surrounding melts or ignites or the battery casing gives way and a small explosion occurs. If you suspect a defective charging /overcharging protection circuit in the laptop or in the battery pack, then remove the battery and speak with your laptop vendor or a laptop service point - by trying to hack something in C# you [play with fire](http://www.theinquirer.net/img/9327/Flaming-Dell.jpg?1241332136).

Comment: does the battery blink or does the LED on the transformer blink? The transformer is always going to be illuminated if it is plugged into the wall.

Comment: @elgonzo You are correct. When the laptop is overcharged, it gets very hot and melts. But I just want to avoid overcharging even if it is not unplugged. And I want to stop charging at a specific level just before the battery becomes hot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard API for disabling charging.

Some manufacturers have added their own circuitry, with special drivers, to allow software control over the charger.  For example, some Compal laptops have included a "Green Charger" utility that stops charging at 80%, in a tradeoff between runtime per charge and runtime decay over the life of the battery.

But those mechanisms are completely proprietary and manufacturer-specific.

Comment: Hello! Does someone know if HP laptops have anything that would allow software to control over the charger?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible via pure software. You need hardware support for it as your OS has no way to change the battery control chip's behaviour unless a special interface is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop does not control charging programmatically. Like elgonzo said, if it kept charging it would overheat and either melt your computer or explode.

Comment: The first sentence isn't necessarily true...  Of course charging ceases when the battery is full, but also when the ambient temperature is too high **or too low**, and in some cases, under software control.

Comment: I think it can be programmically controled. But I dont know how it can be achieved.